# How to fill gap around new exterior vent?

Tags: vent, exterior, siding, gap

How do I fill the gap?

- My hot water tank died, and I had it replaced with a tankless heater.
- The new vent does not fully fill the void from the previous vent, and has a 1" gap around it.
- Contractors are quoting around ~$1,000 to fill void, add exterior flashing, finish interior work.

This seems expensive for the work involved.
I am handy, and suspect I can do better work for less.

Currently, my thoughts are:

- Stuff void with insulation, then finish with steel wool
- Exterior: add flashing and re-caulk
- Interior: leave as if to allow for inspection, or, add some kind of collar
- Someone suggested wrapping the interior / exterior parts of the pipe with plastic to allow it to move?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is the termination cemented in place?

Comment: I didn't think to check - but I don't think it is.

If it isn't, I suppose that means I could pop it off, slide a collar over it, then pop it back on?

That would seal it against the metal base, and then I could flash over that?

Comment: Shouldn't the termination point down, as well?

Comment: Surprisingly, no!

When I read the specs for 240A's and horizontal vents, they're supposed to stick out like this with just a small grade.

Comment: No, these are designed to function horizontally. They're common around here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly I'd want the pipes secured to the wall a bit better to avoid rattling and stabilize for sealing at the exterior. I'd run a one-by or strip of plywood horizontally across two studs just below the two elbows, then add standard pipe straps.

I'd use a block of PVC board stock to overlay the existing trim block. Use a hole saw to cut a suitable hole, then cut the block in half if the pipe termination isn't removable.

Install it with trim-head screws or adhesive, caulking between the halves, then caulk to the top and sides of the block as well as around the pipe.